# In Python, how to present pairs of dicts in human readable form?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, human-readable

Basically, I'm looking for an efficient way (in terms of coding effort) to present a list of pairs of Dicts in a human-readable form. In Python 2.7.

I have two lists of `OrderedDict`. Each dict is a record of book data (title, author etc). One list has messy data (typo's etc), the other has tidy data. I'm using `difflib.SequenceMatcher` to find the closest match of untidy titles, to tidy ones. That works nicely.

It gives me a list of pairs of dicts, namely each untidy dict to it's closest matching tidy one. Those pairs need to be reviewed, pair by pair, by humans. 
So I want to output each pair to the screen, showing the untidy and the tidy dict side by side, each in it's own panel. Each dict may have a varying amount of additional fields, eg.  co-author, publisher, date, etc.

`difflib.HtmlDiff` doesn't really do what I want.

Exporting to Excel (via CSV) is not ideal, because data isn't flat. (One line in excel will have a different number of fields than another). Likewise for Google Refine, I think that's more oriented towards tabular data.

Call me lazy, but Tkinter or XML/HTML seem to be overkill. It's just a once-off exercise.

I'm not familiar at all with JSON nor YAML, maybe I should look there?

Any better suggestions?

I have this hunch that I haven't found the right search terms yet.

Comment: YAML for me , see http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/04/13/yaml-aint-markup-language-completely-different

Comment: If the only constraint is that it should be human-readable, why not just use a Textfile with 3 Columns (key name, untidy value, tidy value)? Of course you would alsi need another line of "header" data for each diff, but that's not much coding effort either.

Comment: What are input and output?

Comment: @user2931409 input is the list of pairs of dicts. Output see edited text.

Comment: @klashxx thanks - time to learn YAML, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I had to output was a list of 3-item lists, each 3-item list containing matching number and two ordered dicts with title-to-correct and best matching title, both with additional info such as author, shelfmark, etc.

I went for output in Yaml, because it's advertised as human-readable and human-editable. For this I have no user testimonial yet, but creating the output file was really easy (if you take time to read the [PyYaml documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)).

```
import yaml
.
.

with codecs.open('Lit_titles_match.yml', 'w', 'utf-8-sig') as m:
    # match is a list of lists of one float and two dicts.   
    m.write(yaml.dump_all(match, default_flow_style=False))
```